# How to handle " unsupported proxy protocol" error in npm?

Tags: node.js, npm

Hi guys I tried to use npm to install some packages but got totally blocked by the error below:

```
C:\Users\XXX> npm install XXX
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm ERR! code EUNSUPPORTEDPROXY
npm ERR! unsupported proxy protocol: 'protocol:'
```

And I don't know what to do. I googled and tried to do something like `npm config set http-proxy null` but of course it didn't work. I didn't find anything about how to set this "protocol" thing in npm docs either.

Could anyone tell me how to handle that? Thank you very much coz right now I basically can't install anything using npm due to the error.

Comment: Do you use a proxy?

Comment: @Marc Normally I don't but sometimes yes. So I don't know if my previous proxy setting like in git-bash could corrupt things in npm. In this case I've tried to toggle on and off proxy but made no difference :\

Comment: What is your Terminal/Shell? Try the Windows cmd/powershell.

Answer (score 1):

Run these two commands one by one-

```
npm config rm proxy

npm config rm https-proxy
```

[image: Please see the image]